# How to monitor number of API calls using Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have a use case where I need to ensure that after a filter is changed on a page, there are only 2 API calls - no more, no less.

How can I achieve this using cypress ?

Answer (score 0):

Gleb Bahmutov has a blog post about using intercepts, and one of his concepts is [counting the number of times a request is matched.](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-intercept-problems/#get-number-of-times-an-intercept-was-matched) You could use that along with a very broad matcher, something like...

```
const getAliasCount = (alias) => {
  // implementation details, use at your own risk
  const testRoutes = cy.state('routes')
  const aliasRoute = Cypress._.find(testRoutes, { alias })

  if (!aliasRoute) {
    return
  }

  return Cypress._.keys(aliasRoute.requests || {}).length
}

it('confirms the number of times an intercept was called', () => {
  cy.intercept({ url: /.*/}).as('myIntercept');
  // test code
  ...
  cy.wait('myIntercept').then(() => {
    const interceptCount = getAliasCount('myIntercept');
    cy.wrap(interceptCount).should('deep.equal', 2);
  });
});
```